# UART and BLE Simultaneously

Tags: embedded, uart, bluetooth-low-energy, nrf52832

I'm using the *nRF52832 Blue Feather module*. This project has an endnode (Master) and many clients (Slaves). So the endnodis e connected to an online server to collect data and send the data to *nRF52832 Blue feather module* over UART.
Then nRF52832 Blue Feather send data ta o specific slave device over BLE.

**So I want to know is it possible to run UART and BLE one after the other if not simultaneously on the same controller (in my case *nRF52832 Blue Feather*)? Does it cause any problem over the long term?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to know is it possible to run UART and BLE one after the other

It is. The whole nRF52 series are designed to support both wired protocols and BT/BLE. Most of the BLE work are shouldered by the Nordic's respective BLE stack, so don't worry. You may want to consider prioritising the data flow, though: When to process the incoming data through UART, when to prepare the data to be sent over BLE, etc. <sup>For further information contact Nordic support.</sup>